# Subdomains on IP addresses in Webmin

Tags: apache2, subdomain, webmin, ubuntu-11.10

How can I set up a subdomain on an IP address using Webmin?

So, if I go to `http://directory.127.0.0.1/` it goes to the same place as `http://directory.localhost/` (`/var/www/directory`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how IP addresses and host names work.

You  have either an [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Address), which can consist only of digits, or a [host name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname), whose components cannot consist only of digits. Host names can have subdomains, IP addresses can't.